# Is there a shorter way to do this than qoq in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I often have to switch between a code and name from a query in my code. Here's what it looks like:

```
<cfquery name="AllLocations" >
    Select Name, Code From Locations 
</cfquery>
```

Later in the page I will need the name and have the code, or visa-versa:

```
<cfquery name="ThisLocation" dbtype="query >
    Select Name From Locations where Code = '#Code#'
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#ThisLocation.Name#</cfoutput>
```

Is there a shorter way to do this so I don't have to do the qoq every time?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing when and why you are doing the q of q and whether or not you really need the entire table to start with.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is if coldfusion has a shorthand I can use that will get the row and column at once. Something like `AllLocations["#Name#"].Code`

Comment: Of course, but what you are trying to do - and more importantly *why* - impact what options are available and which one(s) are preferable for your specific scenario.

Comment: I recommend using the UDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<cfoutput>
#allLocations.name[listfind(valuelist(allLocations.code), code)]#
</cfoutput>
```

**Edit starts here**
Given the comment about performance, I understand that arrays are faster than lists.

```
<cfoutput>
#allLocations.name[arrayFind(allLocations['code'], code)]#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You missed the second argument for `listFind()`

Comment: I do that a lot.  Usually I notice because I actually try to run the code, and fail.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I'm not sure it's any easier (at least to read), but it does work.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg If it matters to you, you may want to perform some timing tests to see which actually performs better.  This code or the QoQ.

Comment: When I return similar data that has a couple unique identifiers (ID, abbreviation and/or code), I use the QueryToStructOfStructures UDF tro allow lookup and access to other column data http://cflib.org/udf/QueryToStructOfStructures